# I can only access rails_admin via cancancan with `can :manage, :all `

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, cancancan

On rails 5. I'm trying to integrate `cancancan 3.0.1` with `rails_admin (1.4.2)` and for the most part it works. My problem is that I can only get routing acccest to work if I give the user `can :manage, :all` otherwise I get an access Denied from cancancan

Here's my cancancan ability code. In this case the super admin gains access whereas the normal admin with `can :manage, Project` does not:

```rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :read, :all                 # allow everyone to read everything

    return unless user && user.admin?

    can :access, :rails_admin      
    can :read, :dashboard           # allow access to dashboard

    if user.superadmin?
      can :manage, :all             # allow superadmins to do anything
    elsif user.admin?
      can :manage, Project
    end
  end
end
```

Is there anyway to allow users onto this route without `manage :all`?